# My sprites in p5.play continue to have a strange halo surrounding them

Tags: image, sprite, p5.js

Does anyone know why all of my sprites (images) have strange halos drawn around them whenever I run my sketch? Am I using the wrong filetype or transparency settings?

[image: codeforsprite]

Comment: please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: And please do not post screenshots of your code, but post your code as text instead, so people can better read it and easily copy it for testing.